# Extending improper integral.

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

Let $(f_n)$ be sequence of continuous functions on the domain $[a,b]$ which converges uniformly to $f$. The function $f$ is continous and so must be integrable. The limit of the integrals ($\displaystyle\int f_n$) is equal to the integral of the limit function $\displaystyle\int f$. So $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n=\int f$.

Show that the result above may not be extended to improper integrals by attempting to apply it to sequence of functions defined by

$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
    (n-|x|)/n^2   & \text{when $x\in[-n,n]$}\\
    0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$

What I didn't understand is that what is question asking. What does it means by "not be extended to improper integrals"? I have evaluated the improper integral of first kind where input of function is bounded by $[-n,n]$ which is $2n^2-\dfrac{|n|}{n}$. And as $n$ approaches $\infty$ or negative $\infty$ the integral approaches to $\infty$ this means limit exist but it is divergent. So this still doesn't satisfy me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improper integrals in this context are integrals with infinite bounds.

What you are being asked is to show that for the given function, $f_n \to 0 $ uniformly on the Real line but that $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_n \not \to 0.$$
The first task is to show uniform convergence.  This is evident because for each $ n $ we have $ | f_n(x)| < 1/n $ for all $x$.

The second task is to evaluate, 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_n(x) ~ dx = 2 \int_0^\infty f_n(x) dx  \\ = 2\Bigg[ \frac{nx - \tfrac{1}{2}x^2}{n^2}\Bigg]_0^n  \\ = 1. $$

Thus $\int f_n $ trivially converges to $ 1 $ but $ \int (\lim f_n ) = \int 0 = 0 $ and these two are not equal.

Thus the principle fails for an unbounded domain.

Comment: Holy Sht so I wasted my hours of time just staring it omg.